# Need help with css

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I want to display Square root symbol(√) inside of a span tag on my apsx page..I want it to display as a tick mark..Now I want it green in color. How do I style this symbol to make it green and wat other properties do I need to set so it appears correctly as a Green tick mark on my page?

When I embedded it inside of a span tag, it said tag not well formed..Which other tag do i need to use if not span ? This tick mark will be initially invisible and will appear only after some button is clicked

Comment: you can use some image having a tick mark

Comment: @serrenity , its better to use image

Comment: I agree, an image to display a check mark is better in this scenario, though @Phil's answer is correct.

Comment: wish I had time to explain why I am not using image..anyway..thnx all for answering :)

Comment: If you want a tick, then use a tick (✓), don't use a square root. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/index.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<span style="color: green;">&radic;</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

what's a tick mark? a check mark? you can do it in css. 
body:nth-of-type(1) .square-root:after {content:"\221A"; color:#008000; font-size:4em; font-weight:900}

that will work. you'll need to change positioning, font-size/weight accordingly. that's using the square root Unicode char; idk what a tick mark is.